# Why is the Leibniz method for approximating pi so inefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, pi

I've been playing around with algorithms for computing pi. One that I noticed is the `leibniz` algorithm.

It states that pi can be approximated like this

$n = 1$ (The first odd number)

$$\pi = 4 \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+2} + \frac{1}{n+4} - \frac{1}{n+6} + \cdots \pm \frac{1}{n + x} \right)$$

The nature of this algorithm is to start with the first odd number 1. Add 1 divided by that odd number, then subtract 1 divided by the next odd number. Flip the signs on every iteration. Finally, multiply this result by 4.

I created an algorithm for this in JavaScript.

```
function leibnez(n) {
    var fraction = 0;
    var denominator = 1;
    var sign = "+";
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sign = i % 2 == 0 ? "-" : "+";
        if (sign == "+") {
            fraction += (1 / denominator);
        }
        else {
            fraction -= (1 / denominator);
        }
        denominator += 2;
    }
    return fraction * 4;
}
```

When calling `leibniz(10000)` which will perform 10000 such fractional additions/subtractions, I get a value of `3.14149` which is accurate only to 4 decimal places.

Calling `leibniz(100000)` results in a value of `3.14158` which is accurate only to 5 decimal places.

Is this algorithm really that inefficient at approximating pi or is the discrepency an error in JavaScript's floating point addition.

Comment: Spoiler: His name is "Leibniz".

Comment: Answer: Because after each second step you have only added $\frac 1 k - \frac 1 {k+2} = \frac 2 {k(k+2)}$.

Comment: Still, I thought the Leibniz was in the Middle Ages. Even the Chinese in the 5th century could calculate pi to 7 digits. This was supposed to be much more efficient

Comment: Well, I think it was not Leibniz' aim to give an efficient algorithm but a nice and beautiful formula.

Comment: Leibniz was more recent than Middle Ages, a contemporary of Newton. And he surely knew much closer approximations of $\pi$; but that was a time when people were finally figuring out the sums of all kinds of simple series like this one.

Comment: +1 for JavaScript. As for the question, the most important thing that this was the first method that could *potentially* allow to compute $\pi$ with infinite precision. The method of polygons could do that too, but it was much harder to operate with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to conditional convergence, the error term is comparable to the last term of the series:

$$\pi=4
\left[
  1-\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}
\right]+(-1)^{n}
\left(
  \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{4n^{3}}+\ldots+\frac{E_{2k}}{2^{2k}n^{2k+1}} +\ldots
\right)$$

**Modern calculations**

[BBP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula)
$$\pi =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{16^{n}}
       \left(
         \frac{4}{8n+1}-\frac{2}{8n+4}-\frac{1}{8n+5}-\frac{1}{8n+6}
       \right)$$

Ramanujan series

$$\frac{1}{\pi} =
  \frac{\sqrt{8}}{9801} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
  \frac{(4n)!}{(n!)^{4}}
  \frac{(1103+26390n)}{396^{4n}}$$

See also [Borwein's algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein%27s_algorithm) for further interests.

Comment: There are many other more efficient algorithms than Leibniz's one: using Machin formula, Chudnovsky series, computing the fixed point of $f(x)=x+\sin(x)$ and starting with $x=3$, Gauss-Legendre, ...

Answer (score 3):

The Leibniz series is OK for calculating $\pi$ to reasonable precision, if Euler acceleration is applied to it. The idea is to replace
$$a_{2n+1}-a_{2n+2}+a_{2n+3}-a_{2n+4}+\cdots$$
with
$$\frac12a_{2n+1}+\frac12(a_{2n+1}-a_{2n+2})-\frac12(a_{2n+2}-a_{2n+3})+\frac12(a_{2n+3}-a_{2n+4})-\cdots$$
For a convergent series, this leaves the sum the same, but the terms are smaller because
$$\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}=\frac1{n(n+1)}$$
So they decrease with $\frac1{n^2}$ instead of $\frac1n$. Now, since
$$\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{(n+1)^2}=\frac{2n+1}{n^2(n+1)^2}$$
We can repeat the process, replacing
$$\frac12(a_{2n+1}-a_{2n+2})-\frac12(a_{2n+2}-a_{2n+3})+\frac12(a_{2n+3}-a_{2n+4})-\frac12(a_{2n+4}-a_{2n+5)}+\cdots$$
with
$$\frac12\cdot\frac12(a_{2n+1}-a_{2n+2})+\frac12\left(\frac12(a_{2n+1}-a_{2n+2})-\frac12(a_{2n+2}-a_{2n+3})\right)-\frac12\left(\frac12(a_{2n+2}-a_{2n+3})-\frac12(a_{2n+3}-a_{2n+4})\right)+\cdots$$
After $k$ repititions starting from the $n^{th}$ term, each term which started out of order $\frac1n$ is now of order $\frac{k!}{2^kn^{k+1}}$
To compute to quad precision, I chose $n=100$ and $k=24$ so as to be of order about $3.70\times10^{-34}$. Here is my program.

```
program leibniz
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: qp = selected_real_kind(33,4931)
   integer, parameter :: Nsum = 100, Nacc = 24
   integer, parameter :: N = Nsum+Nacc
   real(qp), parameter :: one = 1
   real(qp) a(N)
   integer i

   a = [((-1)**(i-1)*one/(2*i-1),i=1,N)]
   do i = 1, Nacc
      a(Nsum+i:N) = [a(Nsum+i)/2,(a(Nsum+i:N-1)+a(Nsum+i+1:N))/2]
   end do
   write(*,*) 4*sum(a)
end program leibniz
```

And it printed out

```
  3.14159265358979323846264338327951
```

The last digit seems to be off by one.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked on a math website so the given answers make sense but nonetheless, I think that the best answer to the title question appears in the comments. The reason Leibniz method for approximating $\pi$ is so inefficient is arguably because efficiency wasn't a large motivation in the development of this formula. For more on the history of the development of it check out [this](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5012/madhava-and-pi) and [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2690896.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A4dbf7ad635b2267090e329876c932cd9). This doesn't hold a lot of historical weight but I am most convinced that Leibniz was not motivated by efficiency by  looking at [his proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Leibniz%27s_Formula_for_Pi/Leibniz%27s_Proof) of this fact. Looks more like someone trying to get a handle on what $\pi$ is than someone trying to compute digits efficiently.